# What does "bewildered fear" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I first saw "bewildered fear" in [a book](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/4776/4776-h/4776-h.htm) by Bertrand Russell:

> And in a more or less analogous way any questioning of what has been taken for granted destroys the feeling of standing on solid ground, and produces a condition of **bewildered fear**.

More instances can be found on the web, including this one from Alfred Kinsey:

> The history of medicine proves that in so far as man seeks to know himself and face his whole nature, he has become free from **bewildered fear**, despondent shame, or arrant hypocrisy.

How could fear be bewildered?!

Comment: The fear isn't bewildered; the person is both bewildered and afraid.

Answer (score 2):

I interpret the phrase as something like lost or wild fear. A type of existential, animalistic fear–that is indeed anxious, as Eddie B. True said. The adjective is simply describing the fear more.

The phrase takes a while make sense, a lot of it depends on context. I personally don't like it, there are surely single words that could be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

My take is it's more akin to anxiety. The referenced person doesn't have a clear take on whether or not a perceived issue is dangerous or not.